# Relative Paths for SDL in Codeblocks

Tags: c++, path, sdl, bmp

How would I write a relative path to a BMP file in SDL, so that my codeblocks project would run on a different computer without the need to edit the image paths and recompile? Also where would I place the corresponding BMP file? Does it go in the bin folder?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nevermind I figured it out. I realized that I was doing something wrong